# How safe is to swith options ON and OFF in a CMake file?

Tags: cmake, thread-safety

I do have a project with an option, which is used to generate related executables, which are generated in lower-level subdirectories, and the higher-level CMakeLists.txt sets the option ON or OFF. For the distribution I need the executables (having option-dependent names) for both the ON and the OFF state. Presently, I set the option, run CMake, set the option, run CMake. Is it safe (primarily thinking about cacheing and threading) if I use something like shown below?

> opt ON
>
> include(generate)
>
> opt OFF
>
> include(generate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it should work without caching:

```
set(<option> ON)
include(generate)

set(<option> OFF)
include(generate)
```

Threading will not be a problem in any case, as interpretation of CMake scripts(*configuration* stage) is **single-threaded** as opposite to *build* stage.

Using `option()` command instead of `set()` will not work, as `option()` does not modify variable if it is already set in the cache.

You may use `set(<option> <value> CACHE ...)` instead of `set(<option> <value>)`, but such increasing of complexity usually is not needed, unless `generate` script explicitely checks cached option's value.

Note, that `generate` script should not only "have option-dependent names", but also shouldn't create *cached* entries which depends on `<option>` value. Otherwise calling script twice with different options is broken.

Comment: Well, in the build stage I see that the components are compiled in an interlaced way, and the final result is that I have two identical copies, under different names. There is no clashes between the two versions, but only the first set() is effective.

Comment: Hm, does your `generate` script use `add_definitions`, `include_directories` or similar commands? These commands assign current variables, which affects on *all* executables which are built in the directory.

Comment: I do useinclude_directories, but they are the same for both versions.

Comment: Could you provide content of `generate` script (in some simplified form) in the question post itself? It is difficult to guess what is going wrong without viewing the script.